# Importing x10 objects into java

Tags: java, managed, x10, x10-language

We need to pass an x10 arraylist[string] to a Java method as an object. What we tried is this.The method signature in Java interface is as follows.

```
public void getX10ArrayList ( ArrayList <String > nameList):
```

We implement that method inside an X10 class as follows.

```
public def getX10ArrayList ( var names : ArrayList [String] ) {
    // do something
}
```

We get a compile error saying interface expected an object of type `x10.util.ArrayList` but we are sending an object of type `x10.util.ArrayList`[ x10.lang.String]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current X10 type system doesn't allow an X10 class to implement a parameterized Java interface.  Although it looks like the right solution is to define the interface as @Darpan suggests:

```java
public void getX10ArrayList(ArrayList[String] nameList);
```

when the Java interface is type-checked, the type parameter is erased from the X10 interface and so the types are different.  Details of the translation from X10 to Java classes can be found in the paper [*Compiling X10 to Java* (Takeuchi et al. 2011)](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2212739).

One possible workaround is to wrap the generic class in a non-parametrized type.  For example:

```java
// MyArrayList.java
import java.util.ArrayList;
class MyArrayList {
    public ArrayList<String> list;
}

// X10ArrayListProvider.java
public interface X10ArrayListProvider {
    public void getX10ArrayList(MyArrayList nameList);
}

// ArrayListProvider.x10
import MyArrayList;
import X10ArrayListProvider;
public class ArrayListProvider implements X10ArrayListProvider {
    public def getX10ArrayList(names:MyArrayList):void {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to declare your interface signature as -

```
Public void getX10ArrayList(ArrayList[String] nameList):
```